# Apache ftp client: соединение виснет после авторизации...

Tags: ftp, java

Есть такой код:

```
this.tftp = new FTPClient();
// @todo: get from ini file
this.tftp.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
this.allFileNames = new ArrayList <String> ();
// CONNECT AND LOGIN
try {
    this.tftp.connect(hostName);
    System.out.println("Connected to " + hostName + ".");
    if (this.tftp.login(userName, password)) {
        System.out.println("Login success.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Login failed.");
    }
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FTPConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    if (tftp.isConnected()) {
        try {
            tftp.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException f) {
            System.err.println("Fatal error.");
        }
    }
    System.err.println("Could not connect to server.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Этот код соединяется нормально с большинством серверов. Но именно на сервере клиента стоят какие-то хитрые настройки и соединение с сервером виснет после авторизации, которая судя по возвращаемому из login значения проходит успешно. Что делать в таком случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась. Нужно было просто перевести клиент в пассивный режим.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте прописать настройки прокси на стороне клиента. Примерно так:

```
System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
System.getProperties().put( "proxyHost", "myProxyServer" );
System.getProperties().put( "proxyPort", "8080" );
```

Пример [здесь](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/javatip42/jw-Example.java.html)

Comment: Не понимаю причем тут прокси?